# Why did the Payment section stopped working after switching primary domain? And - does Form Key Validation On Checkout need to be enabled?

Tags: magento-1, payment-methods, payment, form-key, magento-1.9.4.0

```
Porto theme
```

I switched the primary domain in our Magento 1.9.4 store and then the Payment section of the checkout stopped working altogether - you could select a Payment method by placing a tick in the radio button but it would NOT proceed to the next step.

I found other posts dealing with problems regarding the payment section and they *suggested to Disable the Form Key Validation*. I did that and it made the Payment section work.

**Why is this and do we need to have it enabled or are we going to get by with it disabled?**